# rounding SQL decimal zero and then sum

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, rounding

i need two decimal places for zero , now i have only number zero , should i use decimal function ? but i don't how to integrate to my previous round and sum .

```
     round(sum(NUS),2) AS NUS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `TO_CHAR` with corresponding format modifier to get the required output.

For more info on Number Format Models, refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm).

```
Select to_char(round(sum(NUMS),2), 'fm9999999.00') 
REQUIRED_OUTPUT from TESTDATA1;
```

Refer Sample Output Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d737/6):

Answer (score 1):

```
 1.00 * sum(NUS) AS NUS
```

will do it